# Minimum supported browser(Chrome,IE,Mozilla) version?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-file-upload, dirpagination

i want to know minimum browser version required of Chrome, IE, Mozilla for each and every item listed below:

```
-------------item-------------Chrome----------------IE-------------------Mozilla

bootstrap.js(v3.0.0)----------??????----------------??--------------------??????

angular.js(v1.4.7)------------??????----------------??--------------------??????

dirpagination.js--------------??????----------------??--------------------??????

ng-file-upload.js(v10.1.11)--??????----------------??--------------------??????

bootstrap-colorpicker-module--??????----------------??--------------------??????

ui-bootstrap-tpls.js(v0.1.4.3)-?????----------------??--------------------??????

wysinwyg-----------------------??????----------------??--------------------??????

angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js-??????----------------??--------------------??????

angular-ui-router.js----------??????----------------??--------------------??????

angular-ui-bootstrap.js----------??????----------------??--------------------??????
```

> for example: shows minimum supported version of chrome, IE, Mozilla
>   for bootstrap.js (v3.0.0)
>
> bootstrap.js(v3.0.0)----chrome(v40+)----IE(v9+)------Mozilla(v4+)

as shown in example i want min. supported version (of chrome, IE, Mozilla)for each and every item

Comment: Why don't you look on internet ?

Comment: i tried but i didn't got answer for chrome and Mozilla browser

Comment: Have you even tried ? First search in google lead me to this http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/

Comment: @Weedoze -  
i tried but i didn't got answer for chrome and Mozilla browser

Comment: I just provided you a link..

Comment: i searched for each and every item but i didn't got min. supported version of chrome and Mozilla for all item. they says latest version of chrome and Mozilla supports but i want specific answer(like chrome v44+, Mozilla v43+ etc), latest means which version?

Comment: The answer that you validated provided the last release of each browser... These are the current version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125086/discussion-between-daksh-chandegra-and-weedoze).

Comment: angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js --> Minimum browser support -> IE11 (IE9 & 10 in compatibility mode)
Chrome 37+
Mozilla 28+   [link](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IE 11

Chrome 53.0.2785.143

Mozilla Firefox 45.0
```

Comment: my answer is for above list which are listed by you

Comment: you can use IE 10 also

Comment: @Sam- is your answer for bootstrap version 3.0.0?